# How to add custom content before hook_form()

Tags: forms

Form uploads image and if image is uploaded I'd like it to be displayed before the form. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "before the form"? If you just want to display the file upload element after the image, you might be better off using CSS instead of overriding elements in PHP.

Comment: I don't know how to add something before the form on the page. http://i.imgur.com/BpxQEQP.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hook_form_alter() to add a 'markup' element to the form, with a negative weight so that it floats to the top. For example:

```
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // Only act on my module's form.
  if ($form_id != 'mymodule_form') {
    return;
  }

  $form['top'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => 'This will be at the top of the form!',
    '#weight' => -100,
  );
}
```